# why passing the return value of an asNumber'ed string breaks io?

Tags: iolanguage

I just started the matasano security challenge, and thought about learning IO at the same time.
So now, i'm stuck on challenge 1 where I need to convert a string to base64.

Anyway i've come to the point where i need to convert from binary to decimal, here is my aproach:

```
binToDec := method( bin, <-- program does not enter this method
  dec := 0
  rem := 0
  i := 0

  while ( bin != 0,
    rem = bin % 10
    bin = bin / 10
    dec = dec + rem * 2 pow( i )
    i = i + 1
  )
  return dec
)

toBase64Ascii := method( slice,
  tmp := ""
  for( a, 0, slice size,  <-- construct a string to use with asNumber
    tmp = tmp .. slice at( a )
  )
  dec := binToDec( tmp asNumber ) <-- the line that make the whole thing crash
)

for ( a, 0, bin size, 6,
  tmp := toBase64Ascii( bin slice( a, a + 6 )
  ***some more code***
)
```

there is no error message or anything, the program just hangs indefinitely.

From the documentation:
asNumber
Returns the receiver converted to a number. Initial whitespace is ignored.

So i must say i'm quite confused here, what is happening ?

I would have done some more research but io is imposible to google for...

Comment: Use `iolanguage` when you google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the expected input and output of your `binToDec` method is, but

> ```
> while ( bin != 0,
>   rem = bin % 10
>   bin = bin / 10
>   dec = dec + rem * 2 pow( i )
>   i = i + 1
> )
> ```

is likely an infinite loop. `bin` is a floating point number which is repeatedly divided by `10`, which does not mean that it ever reaches `0`.

> I need to convert a string to base64.

Notice that there are [`asBase64`](http://iolanguage.org/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Sequence/asBase64) and [`fromBase64`](http://iolanguage.org/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Sequence/fromBase64) methods on sequences.

Comment: You're right: this is ans infinite loop. I got confused about the `decToBin` method because my debug print inside said method where not printed. Which brings me to another question, how are expression evaluated in io ? I will look into this myself for now. Thank you !

Comment: It's possible that the output queue was not flushed during the execution of the method. If there would not have been the infinite loop, the debug messages would have been shown.